# Lyndon words and free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups, free-lie-algebras

It is well known that [Lyndon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word#Standard_factorization) form a basis for free Lie algebras. Is there any analog result for free groups? What is the connection between Lyndon words and free groups? Since groups and Lie algebras share many common properties, I believe there may be some connections.

Kindly suggest some references.

Thank you.

Comment: This question sounds way too vague. It's a natural issue to find a basis for a free algebra (in the sense: space + bilinear law) in a variety (e.g., Lie). There's no such analogue in groups. If you're interested, I'd rather recommend to study a bit free groups these objects (free groups and free Lie algebras) and asked a more focussed question if it arises.